# How to use third-party libraries in Qt 6.3.2

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I wanted to use a library in my Qt project which it has three files: One header file (.h file), One static file (.lib), and finally a Dll file which I have to use it along my executable.

I added .h file content to my project but I should introduce .lib file to the Qt linker. I use the following comment for the linker in configuration file:

```
LIBS += Path to lib file
```

But it frequently gives me the following error:

```
Parse error.  Expected "(", got unquoted argument with text "+=".
```

Then I try the following one again:

```
LIBS += "Path"
```

It gives me the above error again, I used the following code too:

```
LIBS += ("Path")
```

But it is not work again. However, How can I introduce .lib file to the linker in Qt 6.3.2?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using *single* quotes: `'`?

Comment: Yeah, I get same error as above.

Comment: Looks like the error comes from the previous lines. Quick googling yields information about cmake and not qmake. In fact I checked the sources of qmake and couldn't find this error message. Since "LIBS += " is a qmake syntax, first of all we have to make sure that it's a *.pro file that you're showing. Is this correct?